# Mongo dbpath on USB Drive

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to store mongo's files on a USB Drive (/media/bernardo/87cf7663-0f73-4b56-9539-a00d4574d110/corinda_experiments/mongodb/) on my Ubuntu 16.04.

In /etc/mongodb.conf, I've already set

```
dbpath=/media/bernardo/87cf7663-0f73-4b56-9539-a00d4574d110/corinda_experiments/mongodb/
```

This is how the permissions of the directory look like:

```
bernardo@bernardo-UX51VZA:~$ ls -ld /media/bernardo/87cf7663-0f73-4b56-9539-a00d4574d110/corinda_experiments/mongodb/
drwxrwxr-x+ 3 mongodb bernardo 4096 Out  1 11:57 /media/bernardo/87cf7663-0f73-4b56-9539-a00d4574d110/corinda_experiments/mongodb/
```

When I try to connect to mongo, this is what I get:

```
bernardo@bernardo-UX51VZA:~$ sudo service mongodb restart
bernardo@bernardo-UX51VZA:~$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.10
connecting to: test
2017-10-01T12:54:52.583-0300 warning: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2017-10-01T12:54:52.583-0300 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:146
exception: connect failed
```

This is how the end of my log file (/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log) looks like:

```
2017-10-01T12:56:53.474-0300 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2017-10-01T12:56:53.474-0300 [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongodb.conf", net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1" }, storage: { dbPath: "/media/bernardo/87cf7663-0f73-4b56-9539-a00d4574d110/corinda_experiments/mongodb/", journal: { enabled: true }}, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log" }}
2017-10-01T12:56:53.474-0300 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen std::exception: boost::filesystem::status: Permission denied: "/media/bernardo/87cf7663-0f73-4b56-9539-a00d4574d110/corinda_experiments/mongodb/", terminating
2017-10-01T12:56:53.474-0300 [initandlisten] dbexit: 
2017-10-01T12:56:53.474-0300 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2017-10-01T12:56:53.474-0300 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2017-10-01T12:56:53.474-0300 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
2017-10-01T12:56:53.475-0300 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
2017-10-01T12:56:53.475-0300 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
2017-10-01T12:56:53.475-0300 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
2017-10-01T12:56:53.475-0300 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
2017-10-01T12:56:53.475-0300 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
2017-10-01T12:56:53.475-0300 [initandlisten] dbexit: really exiting now
```

So it does seem to be a permission problem, but I don't really know hot to solve it.
Any hints?

Comment: Are you sure you are using a current Mongo 3.x version (I wouldn't start with an outdated 2.x Mongo version)? The service name `mongodb` was only used long time ago. Nowadays it is called `mongod`.

Comment: Updated to 3.2.17, but the error persists.

Comment: did you try 'chown -R mongodb:mongodb /media/bernardo/87cf7663-0f73-4b56-9539-a00d4574d110/corinda_experiments/mongodb' ?

Comment: just tried it, still nothing

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I'm trying to mount a **portable MongoDB Windows X64** on a **USB stick**.

The error returned by Mongo on startup was: `Data directory X:\data\db\ not found` which is not exactly the same error as in your case.

Of course the directory existed and there was no particular reason for it not to work.

Finaly, the problem was the **format of the partition** on my USB stick was **exFAT**. I reformatted my USB stick to **NTFS** and it worked immediately.